# How to to feed keras pre-trained model to computational graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, style-transfer

lately I've been playing around with CNNs written in Keras, TF. Unfortunately I've come across one problem there:

In these magnificent tutorials 
( https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/vgg16.py ; rest of the code is here),
 which I highly recommend, maestro loads pre-trained vgg16.tfmodel in very, very ugly way.

```
def __init__(self):
    # Now load the model from file. The way TensorFlow
    # does this is confusing and requires several steps.

    # Create a new TensorFlow computational graph.
    self.graph = tf.Graph()

    # Set the new graph as the default.
    with self.graph.as_default():

        # TensorFlow graphs are saved to disk as so-called Protocol Buffers
        # aka. proto-bufs which is a file-format that works on multiple
        # platforms. In this case it is saved as a binary file.

        # Open the graph-def file for binary reading.
        path = os.path.join(data_dir, path_graph_def)
        with tf.gfile.FastGFile(path, 'rb') as file:
            # The graph-def is a saved copy of a TensorFlow graph.
            # First we need to create an empty graph-def.
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

            # Then we load the proto-buf file into the graph-def.
            graph_def.ParseFromString(file.read())

            # Finally we import the graph-def to the default TensorFlow graph.
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

            # Now self.graph holds the VGG16 model from the proto-buf file.

        # Get a reference to the tensor for inputting images to the graph.
        self.input = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name(self.tensor_name_input_image)

        # Get references to the tensors for the commonly used layers.
        self.layer_tensors = [self.graph.get_tensor_by_name(name + ":0") for name in self.layer_names]
```

And the problem is- I want my own pre-trained model load in the same/similiar way, so I can put the model into the graph of the class I am calling later and if possible, get the last lines of the code here working.(Meaning getting the tensors of wanted layers from the graph.)

All my tries based on **load_model** imported from keras and the comp. graph failed me. Also I didn't want to load it in a completely different way, because I would have to change A LOT of code afterwards- for a newbie kind of a big problem.

Ok, I hope the question will reach the right person and also that it is not too trivial for you :D.

BTW: The complex problem I'm solving, for you to make picture is the **style transfer** also in the same github repository. (https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/15_Style_Transfer.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to load in a keras model into tensorflow basically? Can easily be done with the following code:

```
import keras.backend as k
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf

model = load_model("your model.h5")  # now it's in the memory of keras
with k.get_session() as sess:
    # here you have a tensorflow computational graph, view it by:
    tf.summary.FileWriter("folder name", sess.graph)

    # if you need a certain tensor do:
    sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("tensor name")
```

To have a little read about the get_session function, [click here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/get_session)

to view the graph, you need to load in the folder from the FileWriter with [tensorboard like this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard#launching_tensorboard):

```
tensorboard --logdir path/to/folder
```

Hope this provided some help, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I had no idea you could do such a thing. I'm sure I will use it someday in near future! 
Actually I still can't find a way to incorporate your idea to my code. Later in code, I'm using many times tensors of layers from CNN as attribute of the CNN class. Such as model.input_tensor ; model.get_layer_tensors etc.. 
Do you think it is possible to put data from keras model, that we are able to acquire, into the "self.graph" of mentioned class of  the CNN, that is used for style transfering?

Thank you one more time for your time, I really appreciate the help :-)

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question, but if you want to know if you can use a keras model to feed data to another tensorflow model, then yes. Just get the output and input tensor of the keras model, and feed the output tensor to your other network, while feeding data to the input tensor.